# Deserialize XML to object C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm trying to serialize xml to object, but after serializing my list of transport-agreements is empty. I pretty sure this is quite easy, but i cant find my error.

I have the following xml

```
<transport-agreements type="array">
   <transport-agreement>
     <id type="integer">1047</id>
     <description>Standard</description>
     <products type="array">
       <product>not important</product>
     </products>
   </transport-agreement>
   <transport-agreement>
     <id type="integer">1048</id>
     <description>Standard</description>
     <products type="array">
       <product>not important</product>
    </products>
   </transport-agreement>
</transport-agreements>
```

And i have the following code:

```
var resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TransportAgreementRoot));
var transportAgreements = (TransportAgreementRoot)serializer.Deserialize(resultContent);
```

And my classes:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("transport-agreements")]

    public class TransportAgreementRoot
    {
        [XmlArrayItem("transport-agreement")]
        TransportAgreement[] TransportAgreements { get; set; }         
     }

    public class TransportAgreement
    {
        [XmlElement("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("carrier")]
        public Carrier Carrier { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("products")]
        [XmlArrayItem("product")]
        public Product[] Products { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `var transportAgreements = (TransportAgreementRoot)serializer.Deserialize(resultContent);` to `(TransportAgreement[])serializer.Deserialize(resultContent)`

Comment: are you trying to serialize or deserialize ...?

Comment: pls have look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Comment: deserialize. changed the title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[XmlRoot("transport-agreements")]
public class TransportAgreementRoot
{
    [XmlElement("transport-agreement")]
    public TransportAgreement[] TransportAgreements { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("transport-agreement")]
public class TransportAgreement
{
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use some of on-line converters, which will give you full classes diagram. My fave is: [this one](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net)

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score -1):

I Changed XmlArray to XmlElement.  The Array would add a extra tag which you don't have in the xml file.

```
   [Serializable, XmlRoot("transport-agreements")]

    public class TransportAgreementRoot
    {
        [XmlElement("transport-agreement")]
        TransportAgreement[] TransportAgreements { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! The array of transportagreements is still empty after changing to element